# I'm looking for graphql query for cognite api which will do the query fetch data from 2 views

Tags: graphql

```
{
  "with": {
    "Property": {
      "nodes": {
        "filter": {
          "and": [
            {
              "hasData": [
                {
                  "type": "view",
                  "space": "slb-pdm-dm-governed",
                  "externalId": "Property",
                  "version": "1_6"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "equals": {
                "property": [
                  "node",
                  "externalId"
                ],
                "value": "Entity:L660V486LL11142:f4b7cd41-031d-4621-8332-b0461113c572"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "TimeSeriesProeprtyType": {
      "nodes": {
        "from": "Property",
        "through": {
          "view": {
            "type": "view",
            "space": "slb-pdm-dm-governed",
            "externalId": "TimeseriesPropertyType",
            "version": "1_9"
          },
          "identifier": "f4b7cd41031d46218332b0461113c572"
        },
        "filter": {
          "and": [
            {
              "in": {
                "property": [
                  "slb-pdm-dm-governed",
                  "TimeseriesPropertyType/1_9",
                  "externalId"
                ],
                "values": [
                  {
                    "space": "slb-pdm-dm-governed",
                    "name": "SWITCH_STATUS"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "select": {
    "Property": {
      "sources": [
        {
          "source": {
            "type": "view",
            "space": "slb-pdm-dm-governed",
            "externalId": "Property",
            "version": "1_6"
          },
          "properties": [
            "*"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "includeTyping": false
}
```

I have to write the above graphql query to fetch data from two views but I'm not getting the expected results.

If I get sample query which will join the tables, it will be helpful.

**Scenario :** Find all the property types of the properties that belong to an entity filtered on facets (e.g. where product is "Oil", production flow is "Producing" and method is "Simulated"or "measured".
I'm looking for the query for the above scenario

Comment: GraphQL is *not* a query language. It's middleware that sits between your client(s) and your database(s) - in this case Cognito apparently? The GraphQL server you are hitting should document what queries are possible and their syntax.